# Python plotting issue / masked array / hatching

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

Does anyone know why the following happens; I have an array of data which contains either 1's or 0's. Code below, where `data = np.ma.masked_equal(data, 1)` masks any points where data is 1, leaving hatching on zeros only. This doesn't work as expected (hatches everywhere). Any ideas?

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

data = np.zeros((324,432))
data[:,0:100] = 1

data = data.astype(np.int)

Lons_I,Lats_I = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,360,432),np.linspace(-90,90,324))


m = Basemap(projection='npstere',boundinglat=60,lon_0=0,resolution='c')
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.3)
X, Y = m(Lons_I, Lats_I)
cs = m.contourf(X,Y,data,np.linspace(-5,5,26),cmap='RdBu_r',extend='both')

data = np.ma.masked_equal(data, 1)

plt.pcolor(X,Y,data, hatch=".",alpha=0)
cbar = m.colorbar(cs)


plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: No solutions - is this a bug then?

Comment: If every problem that doesn't get an answer within half a day on SO was a bug, we would have a global software collapse. Reasons not to get a quick answer are mostly that the question does not include a [mcve]. In this case the problem seems independent of basemap, so you can leave that out. It also would not require a huge netcdf file to be downloaded (most people will not download unknown files from the internet).

Comment: As I do not have your data, I cannot reproduce your plot, but I tried with self-generated data, where one area is equal 0 and another equal 1. In this case I cannot reproduce the behaviour you describe. The only thing that comes to mind is that your data would not be exactly 1. (comparing `floats` this way is anyway not a good idea -- try casting your data into `int` before masking, i.e. `data = data.astype(np.int)`

Comment: I have supplied data already - see the hyperlink on the last word 'here'

Comment: And @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, this is a minimal, complete and verifiable example. I could remove the basemap and create a dummy array of data, but seeing as I could not find any reason as to why it wouldn't work, I decided to include this.

Comment: @JamesWarner well could you check if the line `data = data.astype(np.int)` solves your problem? Maybe you also have to throw in an `np.ceil` ...

Comment: @JamesWarner ImportanceOfBeingErnest has got a point -- if you do create some dummy data, can you still reproduce the problem?

Comment: @ThomasKühn I edited my example to make it much more idealised (updated above), but the suggestion you gave made no difference. Thanks though - could you run the above code and verify you obtain the same?

Comment: That's how it should be. Now it's easily reproducible. Two things that are apparent now: the problem is not the hatching, but the area of the pcolor (independent of hatching). The problem is indeed due to the basemap in use. I will try a little further later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not the hatching. It's also not the `np.ma.masked_equal` function. You can try that out by exchanging `0`s to `1`s in the array; this wil port the problem to the `0`s instead of the `1`s.

The route towards the solution leads over ignoring the hatching and using a non-zero alpha. Using much less points, we observe that there are two different shades of the color,

[image]

```
data = np.zeros((18,25))
data[:,0:9] = 1
Lons_I,Lats_I = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,360,25),np.linspace(-90,90,18))

m = Basemap(projection='npstere',boundinglat=60,lon_0=0,resolution='c')
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.3)
X, Y = m(Lons_I, Lats_I)

data = np.ma.masked_equal(data, 1)

plt.pcolor(X,Y,data, alpha=0.3)
```

This tells us that part of the mesh is plotted more often than the other.

The reason is the spherical coordinate system in use. The plot goes once aroud the sphere (0,360), but also half around it in the orthogonal direction (-90,90). The outer points are then connected, such that part of the map is doubly colorized.

In return this means that it is possible to obtain the desired result by not using the complete half sphere. So instead of going from `-90` to `90`, we would start the grid at slightly less, going e.g. from `-89.99` to `90`.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

data = np.zeros((324,432))
data[:,0:100] = 1

Lons_I,Lats_I = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,360,432),np.linspace(-89.99,90,324))

m = Basemap(projection='npstere',boundinglat=60,lon_0=0,resolution='c')
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=0.3)
X, Y = m(Lons_I, Lats_I)
cs = m.contourf(X,Y,data,np.linspace(-5,5,26),cmap='RdBu_r',extend='both')

data = np.ma.masked_equal(data, 1)

plt.pcolor(X,Y,data, hatch=".", alpha=0) 
cbar = m.colorbar(cs)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Ah that's very interesting, makes sense now. Thanks also for taking time to explain the solution to aid understanding.